# c# HttpWebRequest through Org.Mentalis.Network.ProxySocket

Tags: c#, .net, proxy, httpwebrequest, socks

I'm trying to make httpwebrequest through socks5 proxy, using mentalis library.

```
    ProxySocket s = new ProxySocket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    // set the proxy settings
    s.ProxyEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 9050);
    s.ProxyType = ProxyTypes.Socks5;
    s.Connect("www.mentalis.org", 80);

    HttpWebRequest reqTest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.mentalis.org");
```

So i create a socket manually and then connect it tor, then to the target. But now, i need to send a request to mentalis. But i can't find any way to set a socket to `HttpWebRequest`, is it even possible to suply manually connected socket o `HttpWebRequest` ? Or maybe a `NetworkStream`